# Sonar build gives error for :sonar-maven3-plugin:jar:5.4

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonarqube-5.4

I have upgraded the Sonar version to 5.4 and while running the POM to generate the report, getting the below error:

```
[INFO]
[INFO] --- sonar-maven-plugin:2.1:sonar (default-cli) @ HEP05_NY_R2.0_JUNIT_ProviderInformationComponents ---
[INFO] SonarQube version: 5.4
[WARNING] The POM for org.codehaus.sonar:sonar-maven3-plugin:jar:5.4 is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.953 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-05-02T15:19:28-04:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 11M/239M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.1:sonar (default-cli) on project HEP05_NY_R2.0_JUNIT_ProviderInformationComponents: Can not execute SonarQube analysis: Plugin org.codehaus.sonar:sonar-maven3-plugin:5.4 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failure to find org.codehaus.sonar:sonar-maven3-plugin:jar:5.4 in http://10.234.231.225:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of nexus has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
```

Can someone tell, where should I look into resolve the error and let me know if you need more details.

Answer (score 2):

You've tagged your question "sonarqube-5.4" on that basis, I'll say that the version of the Maven plugin you're using is incompatible.

According to [the docs](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Maven), 2.2.1 is compatible through SonarQube version 4.5.x, but not with 5.x.

Comment: Are you mentioning the Maben version? In that case, I have Apache Maven 3.2.5

Comment: No, the version of the SonarQube Scanner for Maven